# Substring between ' ' symbols

Tags: java

`<img src='http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/v1/testFolder/1024x1024.jpg'/>`

I want to get the url which is between `'` and `'`. This is what I tried and it gives String index out of range : -1 error.

```
String html = "<img src='http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/v1/testFolder/1024x1024.jpg'/>";

html.substring((html.indexOf("'")), html.indexOf("'"));
```

and also I tried `html.substring((html.indexOf("'")) +1 , html.indexOf("'"));`

How can I get the url between `'` and `'`?

Comment: Why would `indexOf` for a given character ever give you different results?

Comment: Well, you've already gotten an answer, but the Javadocs are (generally) your friend.

Comment: Please remember this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

You need to retain the first index so that you can search for the next one beyond that point

```
int idx = html.indexOf("'") + 1;
int idx2 = html.indexOf("'", idx); // this will find the next ' character

System.out.println(html.substring(idx, idx2));
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.
What exactly is the point of writing `+ 1`?

Comment: You should try it yourself and see what happens! But the answer is that if you don't have the + 1 it will find the same ' character again

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's observation that he got an out-of-bounds exception: -1.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `System.out.println(html.substring(idx + 1, idx2));` or even better add the `+ 1` in the first line?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change html.indexOf("'") to html.lastIndexOf("'").

try it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String html = "<img src='http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/v1/testFolder/1024x1024.jpg'/>";

    System.out.println(html.substring(html.indexOf("'") + 1, html.lastIndexOf("'")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We need to use `lastIndexOf` for finding the second one as I understand from your answer.

Comment: Yes, you will get string between the first **'** and the last one **'**

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex pattern....

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
m.find();
m.group(1); // will return http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/v1/testFolder/1024x1024.jpg
```